# Is there a deque-like bitset in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, deque, bitset

I am trying to store a very large search mask with a filter of bits.

Both `std::vector<bool>` and `std::bitset<n>` store their bool representations as bits, which is different from a normal bool which is usually the size of a `char` or `int32_t`.

The problem is both of those data structures store their elements in memory in one giant block. The operating systems are getting mad at me for requesting blocks that are too big.  One thing `std::deque<bool>` does is store its elements in something like a linked list I think.

Now I know you cannot use a pointer to a single bit without shifting, and using a linked list type structure defeats the purpose of memory conservation.  But you could store like a 2gig block of `char[]`, use shifts to set individual bits, and then a linked pointer to another 2gb block, you dig?

So tell me if this type of structure exists somewhere or is even possible.

Comment: Can the mask grow? or do you know its size at compile time?

Comment: The size is not known til runtime, so it would technically have to be a dynamic bitset.  Boost has one in the library.

Comment: You may want to also try boost::dynamic_bitset but I think that is similar to std::vector<bool> in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any direct solution to your problem but it could easily be resolved by a custom container.

One solution woudl simply involve std::deque of std::bitset. Where the size of the bitset is a power of 2 such as 256. With this you can take the index and just mask off the deque index and bitset index individually:

```
std::deque< std::bitset<256> > ;
unsigned long long = 1500;

bool val = bigBitset[ index>>8 ][ index & 0xFF ];
```

This could also be encapsulated within a class for convenience:

```
class DequeBitset : public std::deque< std::bitset<256> >
{
public:
    struct Index
    {
        unsigned long index;

        unsigned long dequeIndex() const { return index>>8; }       
        unsigned long bitsetIndex() const { return index&0xFF; }
        Index( unsigned long index ) : index(index) {}
    };
public:

    bool operator[]( const Index& index )
    { return std::deque< std::bitset<256> >::operator [](index.dequeIndex())[ index.bitsetIndex() ]; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DequeBitset test;
    test.resize(10);
    bool val = test[259];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A deque/queue specialized with a desired "block" class (e.g. unsigned char[N], or a wrapper class (even bitset), for convenience) with custom equality and bit-wise operators that operate on corresponding blocks could achieve this.

Those custom bitwise methods would need to determine the blocks/ranges to operate on, by translating each input "global" bit index of an operation into a set of (block number, block local) indices depending on the modifying operation. Non-modifying operations/queries can be implemented as a simple traversal over all blocks.

The general idea is that you split the bitmask into blocks and operate on those sequence of blocks, since depending on memory fragmentation, you may not be able to allocate 2GB or more of contiguous memory at *runtime*. Of course, the smaller the block size, the more you suffer from processing overhead, reduced cache coherency, and memory fragmentation, however, in your client application you may be able to  squeeze more memory out of, well, your memory.

Seems like there is already an implementation of this as @Crog mentioned: [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many 2GB blocks you can use. But let's say you need 2048 2GB blocks. Then why not store pointers to 2GB blocks in a vector, i.e., `std::vector<uint8_t*>` and add new 2GB block into this vector as you need to expand the structure.